# How do you insert characters into middle of string? C++

Tags: c++, string, xcode

The purpose of this code is to insert an `x` in between repeating letters. For example, if I were to input `"CoolBoolFallmoose"`, the output would be `"CoxolBoxolFalxlmoxose"`.

The code is also supposed to make an even number of pairs of letters, so if there is an odd amount of characters, an `x` is added to the end of the string. An example for this would be if we had `"ball"`, it would become `"balxlx"` to make even pairs: `"ba"` `"lx"` `"lx"`.

This is the code I have so far:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string cipher, plain, paired = "";
    cout << "input plaintext(no spaces, lowercase):\n";
    cin >> plain;

    for (int i=0;i<plain.length();i++){
        if (plain[i]==plain[i+1]){
            plain.insert(i,'x');
        }
        paired[i]=paired[i];
        cout<<paired[i];
    }
   
    if (paired.length() % 2!= 0){
        paired=+'x';
    }
    
    cout<<paired<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is just the same as my input, no `"x"` added in any place.

The issue I am having is, every time I try to use the `append()` or `insert()` function for strings, I get an error from my compiler, which is xCode. Is there another way to solve this code?

**EDIT**: The error says:

> No matching member function to call for insert

It also comes up for `append()`.

Comment: It is unclear with the case of odd numbers of duplicated characters. Show an example.

Comment: `insert` is the correct function to use.  If you are getting a compiler error, please post that error here, as text, not a picture.

Comment: Yes, please post the error you get :)

Comment: `plain` is modified, and then you print `paired`... Not clear what you expect to get.

Answer (score -1):

I don't really know what you wanted to do with this part:

```
paired[i]=paired[i];
cout<<paired[i];
```

but otherwise the logic is good. Here is my take on it, `x` is a counter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string m,n;
    int x = 0;
    
    cout << "Input: " << endl;
    getline(cin, m);
    
    for(int i = 0;i < m.length();i++){
        x++;
        n = n + m[i];
        if(m[i] == m[i+1]){
            n = n + 'x';
            x++;
        }
    }
    if((x % 2) != 0){
        n = n + 'x';
    }
    cout << n;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the available overloads of [`std::string::insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert), you will see that your statement `plain.insert(i,'x');` does not match any of them, hence the compiler error.  The overloads that takes a single `char` require either:

- an `index` **and a `count`** (you are omitting the `count`)
- an `iterator` and an optional `count`

There is, however, a couple of overloads that take just an `index` and a value, but they require a `const char*` or a `std::string`, not a single `char`.

Also, `paired[i]=paired[i];` is a no-op. Except in your case, since `paired` has a `size()` of 0 since you never append anything to `paired`, so actually any access to `paired[...]` is *undefined behavior*.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string plain, paired;
    cout << "input plaintext(no spaces, lowercase):\n";
    cin >> plain;

    paired = plain;
    for (string::size_type i = 1; i < paired.size(); ++i){
        if (paired[i] == paired[i-1]){
            paired.insert(i, 1, 'x');
            // or: paired.insert(paired.begin()+i, 'x');
            // or: paired.insert(i, "x");
            // or: paired.insert(i, string{'x'});
            // or: paired.insert(paired.begin()+i, {'x'});

            ++i; // skip the x just inserted
        }
    }
   
    if (paired.size() % 2 != 0){
        paired += 'x';
    }
    
    cout << paired << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/4ViUWe)

Answer (score -1):

A couple of points

First, Although the string.insert function says it takes an int as its first argument it really  wants an iterator in this case.

Second, you are inserting elements into your "plain" string which increases its length and you have plain.length within your loop so you create an infinite loop.

Third, insert inserts BEFORE the index so you need to add 1 to I.

The code below will work for your loop:

```
Int len = plain.length();

Int count = 0;

for (int i = 0;  i < len + count; i++)
   {
       If (plain[i] == plain[i + 1])
          {
             plain.insert(plain.begin() + (i +1), 'X');
             ++count;
          }
   }

cout << plain;
```

And as, mentioned below, if you want to handle spaces you can use getline(cin, plain) instead of cin.